# Unable to override views in meanjs

Tags: mean-stack, mean.io

I want to override article page in `mean.io`. I have created a module comments and added this code in routes.

```
angular.module('mean.comments').config(['$stateProvider', '$viewPathProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $viewPathProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state('comments example page', {
            url: '/comments/example',
            templateUrl: 'comments/views/index.html'
        });

        $viewPathProvider.override('articles/views/view.html', 'comments/views/article.html');

    }
]);
```

And here is articles module dependency injection in `comments/app.js`

```
Comments.angularDependencies(['mean.articles']);
```

But this is not working. Can someone help me doing this?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? are you updating the route.js under comments?

Comment: No errors in console, and this is routes file.